# No sound from XonarSoundcard after weekly update of Lubuntu 22.10

Tags: lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

Xonar card is seen by Alsamixer as default 1 (not default 0) but PulseAudio volume control displays "No cards available for configuration" Output is SPDIF.
Supplement:
File /etc/asound.conf has been created with defaults set to card 1.
Now Alsamixer displays Xonar by default. However
lspci -nn | grep Audio
does not show the Xonar card:
22:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fb8] (rev a1)
25:00.3 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:1457]
Looking for sources and sinks results in the following:
$ pactl list short sources
35      auto_null.monitor       PipeWire        float32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
$ pactl list short sinks
35      auto_null       PipeWire        float32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The following series of commands appears to have resolved the issue by eliminating pipewire:

```
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire-media-session.service
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire pipewire-pulse
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
sudo apt remove pipewire-audio-client-libraries pipewire
```